# values lower than 10 in python dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

hello there I want to get the values in `dict` which are lower than number `10` and count them , here is my code.

**my code :**

```
counter = 0
dict = {'one': [3, 9, 5, 13], 'two': [6]}

    for values in dict :
        if dict.values() < 10 :
            counter = counter + 1
```

the output should be like `counter = 4` if we print out `counter` but i dont how to compare it .

Comment: `counter = len(list(x for values in dict.values() for x in values if x<10))`

Comment: Better not to use `dict` as a variable name, you're shadowing the builtin `dict` (and it's not very informative, either).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An efficient way to do it is a generator comprehension that flattens the nested `.values()` of the dictionary and counts them using `sum`. It is similar to `@matszwecja`'s comment, but potentially faster because it doesn't store the values in a list.

```py
my_dict = {'one': [3, 9, 5, 13], 'two': [6]}
counter = sum(1 for values in my_dict.values() for v in values if v < 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
counter = 0
d_ = {'one':[3,9,5,13], 'two':[6]}
for ki, Lb in d_.items():
    for b_ in Lb:
        if b_ < 10:
            counter += 1
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
res = []
[res.extend(sub) for sub in dict.values()]
print(len([num for num in res if num < 10]))
```